# Logic error with Game of Life (C++)

Tags: c++, logic, conways-game-of-life

Working on Conway's Game of Life and I feel I am very close to finishing it, but there is some flaw in my logic. I've poured over this for hours now and I just feel a second pair of eyes are going to be able to spot my mistake much quicker than I will. My program compiles just fine but the output does not follow the guidelines for the game in specific spots(ex col 0, row 1 has life in the second generation when it shouldn't but all of row 10 appears to be working as intended). For anyone unfamiliar:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules

I am almost certain that the logic error takes place in the function advGen. The following link holds the contents for bacteria.txt that the function readGrid uses: http://pastebin.com/6vurFRSB

Thank you for taking the time to read and help if you choose to do so.

```
    //sample setup to start the game of life - startlife.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;

//initial function prototypes
void initGrid(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE]);
void readGrid(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE]);
void printGrid(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE]);
void advGen(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE]);

int main()
{
    bool life[SIZE][SIZE];
    bool nextGen[SIZE][SIZE];

    readGrid(life, nextGen);
   /* for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++){
        determineNextGen(life);
    }*/

    printGrid(life, nextGen);
    advGen(life, nextGen);
    printGrid(life, nextGen);

    return 0;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------

           readGrid (and related functions)

---------------------------------------------------------*/

void readGrid(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE])
{
    ifstream infile("bacteria.txt"); //see class site project#5 for data file

    int numBacteria, row, col;

    initGrid(life, nextGen);

    infile >> row >> col;
    while (infile){
        life[row][col] = true;
        infile >> row >> col;
    }
    infile.close();
}


void initGrid(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++){
            life[row][col] = false;
        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++){
            nextGen[row][col] = false;
        }
    }
}

void printGrid(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE])
{
    cout << "  01234567890123456789" << endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << row;
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
        {
            if (life[row][col])
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void advGen(bool life[][SIZE], bool nextGen[][SIZE])
{
    int neighbor = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
        {
            if (row == 0)
            {
                if (col == 0)
                {
                    if (life[row + 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (col == 19)
                {
                    if (life[row + 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (life[row + 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (row == 19)
            {
                if (col == 0)
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (col == 19)
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (col == 0)
            {
                if (row == 0)
                {
                    if (life[row + 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                }
                else if (row == 19)
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
             if (col == 19)
            {
                if (row == 0)
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                }
                else if (row == 19)
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                {
                    if (life[row - 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row - 1][col + 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if (life[row + 1][col - 1] == true)
                        ++neighbor;
                    if ( (life[row][col] == true) && (neighbor < 2 || neighbor > 3))
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = false;
                    }
                    else if ( (life[row][col] == false) && (neighbor == 3) )
                    {
                        nextGen[row][col] = true;
                    }
                }neighbor = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
        {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
            {
                life[row][col] = nextGen[row][col];
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: You have a lot of repeated code in there that would benefit from being moved into seperate functions. It would make your code much easier to read.

Comment: _Every single_ use of `== true` you have is 100% redundant on top of being visual noise. Your _huge_ stack of `if(life[...][....]) ++neighbour` could be much simplified to just a few lines if you just cast those `bool`'s to `int` and added them together. And to avoid boundary logic at the price of extra memory taken, you could pad the board on the left, right, top and bottom with zeros and never write over them.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is double counting the number of neighbors. This is because, for example, if `row` is 0 and `col` is 0, it does the `row == 0` case at the top and also the `row == 0` case inside the `col == 0` if statement about 100 lines further down.

One way to fix this is with the right `else` clauses. i.e. do something like:

```
if (row == 0)
{
    ...
}
else if (row == 19)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

You would need to do this for the column case as well.

A better solution is to look at all those special cases and try to rationalize them into something with less repeated code.

What you are trying to achieve is to prevent reading outside of the array boundaries.

An easy way to do that is to have a function to get the value of the array at `row, col` which checks `row` and `col` and returns `false` if `row` or `col` is out of bounds. You can then just call that function for each of the 8 surrounding blocks for each position without having special cases for row 0 and 19 and col 0 and 19.

I suggest trying to write a function like the one above, rather than me just pasting it here for you.

Edit: Also note - you don't always set a value into `nextGen`, so you are killing off cells that had life with 2 or 3 neighbors, you may need to rethink your if/else statement when assigning into `nextGen`

Comment: I'd vote this up, but I am too new. I am very thankful for your explanation, and I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried my hand at writing the function you suggested but before I embarrass myself with even more of my code, can you try to explain what the function does a different way?

Comment: The function needs to take the `life` array as a parameter and parameters for `row` and `col`. It then needs to check that `row` and `col` are inside the array (i.e. >=0 and < SIZE). If they are OK, just return the value from the array. If they aren't OK, then return `false`, which indicates there is no life outside of the boundaries.